# Sum of remainders over the entire array for several queries

Tags: algorithm, sum, modular-arithmetic

I am looking at this challenge:

> You are provided an array **A[ ]** of **N** elements.
>    Also, you have to answer **M** queries.
>    Each query is of following type-
>
> Given a value **X**, find **A[1]%X + A[2]%X + ...... + A[N]%X**
>
> - **1<=N<=100000**
> - **1<=M<=100000**
> - **1<=X<=100000**
> - **1<=elements of array<=100000**

I am having a problem in computing this value in an optimized way.
How can we compute this value for different X?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you seen any formula of modular arithmetics?

Comment: Formula I know of is - (A%X + B%X ) %X = (A+B)%X. I need only (A%X + B%X ) . I tried a lot to figure out if it is possible to obtain the sum of remainders. But I didn't get any formula.

Comment: @harold No, that's incorrect as it'll give (A[1]%X + A[2]%X + ...... + A[N]%X )%X instead of A[1]%X + A[2]%X + ...... + A[N]%X.

Comment: @user249117  It is worth to include this information in question body to prevent hasty comments and answers.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way that you could *at least reduce* the multiplicative factor in the time complexity.

---

In the C standard, the modulo (or remainder) is defined to be `a % b = a - (a / b) * b` (where `/` is integer division).

A naive, iterative way (possibly useful on embedded systems with no division unit) to compute the modulo is therefore (pseudo-code):

```
function remainder (A, B):
  rem = A
  while rem > B:
    rem -= B;
  return rem
```

But how does this help us at all? Suppose we:

- **Sort** the array `A[i]` in ascending order
- Pre-compute the sum of all elements in `A[] -> S`
- Find the first element (with index `I`) greater than `X`
- From the pseudocode above it is clear that *at least* (one multiple of) `X` must be subtracted from all elements in the array from index `I` onwards. Therefore we must subtract `(N - I + 1) * X` from the *sum* `S`.

  - Even better: we can keep a variable (call it `K`, initialize to zero) which is equal to the *total multiple of* `X` we must subtract from `S` to find the sum of all remainders. Thus at this stage we could simply add `N - I + 1` to `K`.
- Repeat the above, finding the first element greater than the next limit `L = 2X, 3X, ...` and so on, until we have passed the end of the array.
- Finally, the result is given by `S - K * X`.

Pseudocode:

```
function findSumOfRemainder (A[N], X):
   sort A
   S = sum A
   K = 0
   L = X
   I = 0

   while I < N:
      I = lowest index such that A[I] >= L
      K += N - I + 1
      L += X

   return S - K * X
```

---

What is the best way to find `I` at each stage, and how does it relate to the time-complexity?

1. *Binary search*: Since the entire array is sorted, to find the first index `I` at which `A[I] >= L`, we can just do a binary search on the array (or succeeding *sub-array* at each stage of the iteration, bounded by `[I, N - 1]`). This has complexity `O( log[N - I + 1] )`.
2. *Linear search*: Self-explanatory - increment `I` until `A[I] >= L`, taking `O( N - I + 1 )`

You may dismiss the linear search method as being "stupid" - but let's look at the two different extreme cases. For simplicity we can assume that the values of `A` are "uniformly" distributed.

- `(max(A) / X) ~ N`: We will have to compute very few values of `I`; binary search is the preferred method here because the complexity would be bounded by `O([NX / max(A)] * log[N])`, which is much better than that of linear search `O(N)`.
- `(max(A) / X) << N`: We will have to compute *many* values of `I`, each separated by only a few indices. In this case the total binary search complexity would be bounded by `O(log N) + O(log[N-1]) + O(log[N-2]) + ... ~ O(N log N)`, which is *significantly worse* than that of linear search.

So which one do we choose? Well this is where I must get off, because I don't know what the optimal answer would be (if there even is one). But the best I can say is to set some *threshold value* for the ratio `max(A) / X` - if greater then choose binary search, else linear.

---

I welcome any comments on the above + possible improvements; the range constraint of the values may allow better methods for finding values of `I` (e.g. radix sort?).

Comment: I tried almost similar approach, but this gets time out .

Comment: @user249117 Have you tested the code separately (i.e. on local machine)? I don't mean to offend - but it may be an infinite loop or other logic error inside the code

Comment: No No. It got partially accepted on small test cases, and doesn't time out on those. I tested it properly. When the multiples get large enough neither Binary search nor Linear search kinda approach fits. And I tried it through various thresholds as well.

Comment: @user249117 please post your code; also, did you try to benchmark each stage of the algorithm? (it could be the sorting that's causing a timeout)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int t;

    cin >> t;

    while(t--){

        int n;

        cin >> n;

        int arr[n];

        long long int sum = 0;

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

            cin >> arr[i];

        }

        cout << accumulate(arr, arr+n, sum) - n << '\n';

    }

}
```

In case you don't know about accumulate refer [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/accumulate-and-partial_sum-in-c-stl-numeric-header/).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).